# html2canvas some is working some no

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, html2canvas

I have a problem,and I don`t understand.. absolute..

So I tried to use `html2canvas.js`. I want to render html to img. The content is in modal. Till here no any problems. 
When I try to render that area what I want the `toDataUrl()` is empty.
But when I try to render a simple button,its working!

Both of is in a `Modal`. My code:

```
     <div class="modal-body ">
        <div class="print" id="printDiv">
            <div class="rows nopm">
                <div class="full">
                    <div class="head"> 
                        Make & Model
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['make']}}  {{$data['model']}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rows nopm">
                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/age.png')}}"> Age
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['age'])->format('m/Y')}} 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/enginesize.png')}}"> Engine Size
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['eng_size']}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/vrt.png')}}"> VRT
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['vrt_date'])->format('m/Y')}} 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/power.png')}}"> Power
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['eng_hp']}}PS ({{$data['eng_kw']}}KW)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/roadlicence.png')}}" > Road tax
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['vrt_price']}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/fuel.png')}}" > Fuel 
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['fuel']}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/mileage.png')}}" > Mileage
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['mileage']}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="half">
                    <div class="head">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/vehicle_icon/transmission.png')}}"> Transmission
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {{$data['trans']}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rows nopm">
                <div class="quatrohead">
                    Extras
                </div>
                <div class="quatro">
                    @foreach($data_extra as $extra)
                        @if ($loop->last) 
                            {{$extra}}
                        @else 
                            {{$extra}},
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="quatrohead"> 
                    Price
                </div>
                <div class="quatroless">
                    &euro;{{$data['price']}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="targetCanvas">
        <img class="imageCanvas" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="print">Print</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script>
    $('#printModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                html2canvas($('#print'), { //like that its working ,with #printDiv no
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        theCanvas = canvas;   
                        console.log(theCanvas.toDataURL());

                       document.querySelector('.imageCanvas').src = theCanvas.toDataURL();

                    }
                });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your script in

```
$(window).load(function (){
       //Your script here
})
```

Or you could try with

```
    setTimeout(function (){
        html2canvas($('#print'), { //like that its working ,with #printDiv no 
        onrendered: function (canvas) { 
        theCanvas = canvas;
        console.log(theCanvas.toDataURL()); 
       document.querySelector('.imageCanvas').src = theCanvas.toDataURL(); 
      } 
     });
    },1000)
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function`error now

Comment: You should place the complete script which is inside script tag into window.load

Comment: `data:, ` same situation.

Comment: Same html, if you place it out side of the modal. Is it working? If yes, `position: relative; display: block;` to your div

Comment: Yes,like that is working,just no image :) empty transparent image,just the html get heigher. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135799/discussion-between-gari-and-kiran-reddy).